# Firebase Authentication Failure

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I added Firebase Authentication to my app. I used Firebase docs and codded. I can sign up and get exception like "this email already in use" succesfully.
When I use sign in button; if I do not close the app after create account, it does not care about password is true or not or null, it just works. After close and re-open the app I get toast msg that says "An internal error has occured. [INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS]"

Am I missing something ?

I will add gradle files and codeblocks

app level dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'

}
```

project level

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

and the codes for sign in and sign up

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    fun btnSignIn(view:View){

        val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordText.toString()

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent = Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }

    fun btnSignUp(view: View) {

        val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordText.toString()

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Sign-up success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did Meet Bhavsar's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here mistake edittext get text missing
check this code

both function

In **btnSignIn()** password edittext text missing

In **btnSignUp()** password edittext text missing

```
    fun btnSignIn(view:View){

        val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordText.text.toString()

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent = Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }

    fun btnSignUp(view: View) {

        val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordText.text.toString()

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Sign-up success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think I was blind 'till read your answer :) This solved, Thanks

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as correct